# Transformation of expected value

Tags: lebesgue-measure, stochastic-analysis

Given a $P$-integrable Random variable $Y$ with density $f$ in the Lebesgue-measure $\lambda$ $(Y(P)=f \lambda$). Derive formulas for the expected value and variance of $Y$.
The definiton is
$$\mathbb{E}_P(Y)=\int Y dP $$
however in the real space something like

$$\mathbb{E}_P(Y)=\int y f(y) dy$$ or
$$\mathbb{E}_P(Y)=\int y f(y) \lambda dy$$

should be true, how can you prove that? I don't understand this very well, my approach

$$\mathbb{E}_P(Y)=\int Y dP =\int Y(\omega) dP(\omega)=\int Y(P(\omega)) d\omega = \int f(\omega)\lambda(\omega) d\omega =...=\int y f(y) \lambda(dy) $$

Hints would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,P\rangle$ denote a probability space and let $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be a random variable.

If $\mathcal B$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel-sets of $\mathbb R$ then this means actually that $\{Y\in B\}:=Y^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal A$ for every $B\in\mathcal B$.

Random variable $Y$ induces a probability measure $P_Y$ on measurable space $\langle\mathbb R,\mathcal B\rangle$ where $\mathcal B$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets.

This $P_Y:\mathcal B\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $B\mapsto P(\{Y\in B\})$.

So for $B\in\mathcal B$ we have:$$P(\{Y\in B\})=P_Y(B)$$

This can also be written as:$$\int1_{B}(Y(\omega))P(d\omega)=\int1_B(y)P_Y(dy)$$

And it can be shown that it is okay to generalize:$$\int g(Y(\omega))P(d\omega)=\int g(y)P_Y(dy)$$for suitable functions $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Applying this on the identity we get:$$\mathsf EY=\int Y(\omega)P(d\omega)=\int yP_Y(dy)$$

If $P_Y$ has a PDF $f$ wrt Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ then it can expanded:$$\mathsf EY=\int Y(\omega)P(d\omega)=\int yP_Y(dy)=\int yf(y)\lambda(dy)$$